# Why x-editable-rails gem throwing an error: undefined method `xeditable?'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, x-editable

I installed the gem x-editable for rails:

```
# x-editable
gem 'x-editable-rails'
```

I added the method `xeditable?` to the `ActionController`:

```
  # Add a helper method to your controllers to indicate if x-editable should be enabled.
  def xeditable?
    true # Or something like current_user.xeditable?
  end
```

But still getting an error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `xeditable?' for #<#<Class:0x007f9012e30f68>:0x007f9012ee9e78>):
    14: 
    15:     .panel-body
    16:       /a.doc_title.editable id='doc_title_12345' data-name="doc[title]" data-title="Enter doc title" data-type="text" data-url='/docs/12345' href='#doc_title_12345' = doc.title
    17:       = editable doc, :title
    18: 
  app/views/docs/_single_doc_in_accordion.html.slim:17:in `_app_views_docs__single_doc_in_accordion_html_slim__2506304306156466629_70128411437560'
  app/views/docs/index.html.slim:52:in `_app_views_docs_index_html_slim___3263534966956214695_70128384677640'
```

Where should I define the method `xeditable?` so that it starts working?

## Update:

This is `application_controller.rb` :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

end
```

This is `application_helper.rb` :

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # Add a helper method to your controllers to indicate if x-editable should be enabled.
  def xeditable?
    true # Or something like current_user.xeditable?
  end
end
```

Now I get new error: same as `xeditable?`, but with `can?` (method undefined)

Comment: how did you call the method?

Comment: puts your `xeditable?` method to ApplicationHelper and try again

Comment: @majioa, I do not call the method, it is a part of auth mechanisms (as described by x-editable-rails)

Comment: @Monk_Code, it does not work

Comment: how did you add the method into a controller? show a part of code! into which controller did you add the method? If you've added the method into a helper, did you included the helper into its controller?

Comment: add `helper_method :xeditable?` below `def xeditable?; true; end`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `helper_method :xeditable?` in your `ApplicationController.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :xeditable?

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  # Add a helper method to your controllers to indicate if x-editable should be enabled.
  def xeditable?
    true # Or something like current_user.xeditable?
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves the problem with `xeditable?`, but the same problem appears with `can?` (as I see in the source they both are used in the if statement)

Comment: If you need additional, just write this: `helper_method :xeditable?, :can?` You don't need `ApplicationHelper` actually. See my edit.

Comment: `helper_method :xeditable?, :can?` doesn't work. Still the `can?` method is undefined

Comment: I just defined the fake `can?` method (I don't use real auth yet):

`def can?(role, object)
    true # Or something like current_user.xeditable?
  end
`

Comment: Is everything ok after defining a new method for `can?`?