# How to use x_editable_rails for editing comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Not sure why i am getting this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm8To.png) when implementing gem x_editable_rails to allow comments to be edited without users being brought to a separate edit page.

x_editable_rails demo app shows that perhaps the right way should be `<%= editable @comment, :content %>,` but because I am looping all comments in the @comments instance variable, doing that throws an error too.

**EDIT**

I changed the line of code from `<%= editable @comments.comment %>` to `<%= editable [comment.article, comment], :content, url: edit_article_comment_path(comment.article, comment) %>` and now, its showing
[undefined method `xeditable?' error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO6Va.png).

I have added the below helper method and added this (helper_method :xeditable?) to application controller. (I don't use cancan so i have added a dummy can? as suggested on this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661986/why-x-editable-rails-gem-throwing-an-error-undefined-method-xeditable).

```
module ApplicationHelper

def xeditable?
  current_user.xeditable?
end

  def can?(role, object)
     true 
  end
end
```

_comments.html.erb

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= editable [comment.article, comment], :content, url: edit_article_comment_path(comment.article, comment) %>
  <%= link_to "Delete comment", [comment.article, comment], method: :delete %>
  <%= link_to "Edit comment", edit_article_comment_path(comment.article, comment) %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Routing

The original error you posted indicates you do not have a route for `APP_DOMAIN/comments/:id`, and that's confirmed by your routes -- comment is a nested resource in your routing, routed like `APP_DOMAIN/articles/:id/comments/:id`.

Note that for unusual routing (i.e. not a typical Rails naming pattern), [x-editable-rails allows you to specify your path](https://github.com/werein/x-editable-rails#making-things-editable). Maybe comments are routed through another name, like `url: post_critique_path(@comment.post, @comment)`.  I see you have now done this, though I'm not sure if it is necessary since your routing is standard pratice.

*Note that I have not tested this myself.* The README is not super clear on what are the allowed or expected values for `:url`. And, confusingly, the gem has a `:nested` option – [which appears to be about setting the `title` HTML attribute](https://github.com/werein/x-editable-rails/blob/master/lib/x-editable-rails/view_helpers.rb#L39:L42).

#### Application helper methods

For your next error, it appears you are implementing the advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20663020/1651458). But I believe you have missed a line, and your ApplicationHelper module should look like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  helper_method :xeditable?, :can

  def xeditable?
    current_user.xeditable?
  end

  def can?(role, object)
     true 
  end
end
```

Comment: no.. but i changed it to def xeditable? object = nil
                                       true
                                    end

Comment: @diana It sounds like perhaps my suggestion corrected your most recent error, and that you now see a new error. If that's correct, I suggest submitting a new SO question with your issue details, and mark this answer as correct. If instead you still see the same error as before, I suggest adding the relevant details to your answer for someone else to provide an alternate answer.